# Python: Filehandle o manejo de ficheros

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy trabajando (y aprendiendo) con los ficheros externos en python, tengo que hacer un programa que lea los números de un fichero de texto que tiene un número en cada línea,y dilucida el mayor y el menor de esos números,escribiendo esos números en orto archivo de texto siendo el mayor y el menor los dos primeros, yo he intentado esto:

```
mayor=0
 menor=999
 lista=[]
 fichero_a=open('numeros5_4.txt','r')
 #fichero_b=open(raw_input('Introduzca el nombre del archivo: '),'w')
 for linea in fichero_a:
    lista.append(linea)
    if lista[linea]>mayor:
       mayor=lista[linea]
    if lista[linea]<menor:
       menor=lista[linea]
    lista.insert(0,mayor)
    lista.insert(1,menor)
 print lista
```

Mi criterio es trasladarlo a lista para manipularlo, pero lo de volver a escribir los números con el mayor como primero y el menor como segundo no lo pillo, de hecho me da error cuando corro el programa,(lo de pasarlo al otro archivo lo hago después una vez solucionado el problema.)
El tipo de error que me da es éste

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Creo que lo que he intentado para saber cual es el mayor y el menor es lo habitual, pero aparte de darme error no sé como hacer para que aparezcan primero y segundo de los números en el otro archivo de texto en el que cada número debe ir en una línea

Answer (score 2):

Entre tantas formas de hacerlo, podrías hacer uso de listas para poder utilizar los métodos `min` y `max` y de esta forma evitar el uso de condicionales (`if`, ...).

Partiendo del siguiente fichero:

```
1
10
3
5
2
4
1
2
12
14
51
21
100
9
76
45
23
45
12
```

**Código**

```
numbers = []
# Abrimos el fichero en modo lectura:
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as file_numbers:
    # Por cada número en los números que hemos recogido:
    for number in file_numbers:
        # Añadimos en la lista cada número convirtiéndolo previamente en un int para poder hacer uso de max y min:
        numbers.append(int(number))
```

Luego si **imprimimos el resultado**:

```
print("El mayor valor de la lista es:", max(numbers))
print("El menor valor de la lista es:", min(numbers))
```

**Tendremos**:

```
$ -> python3 numbers.py
El mayor valor de la lista es: 100
El menor valor de la lista es: 1
```

Uso `with open` por que de esta forma no tendré que cerrar el fichero. Ya se encargaría "automaticamente" de cerrarlo sin necesidad de un `close`.

Luego podrás guardarlo en otro fichero, por ejemplo en `final.txt` de igual forma con `open`. En este caso usaré el modo 'a' de append (utilizo %d como "placeholder" para valores `int` o `float`. Es como usar `printf` en muchos lenguajes de programación. De esta forma "formateamos" la cadena):

```
with open('final.txt', 'a') as fichero_salida:
    fichero_salida.write('%d\n' % min(numbers))
    fichero_salida.write('%d\n' % max(numbers))
```

Podría haber utilizado (para una mejor legibilidad quizá):

```
fichero_salida.write(min(numbers))
```

Pero arrojaría un **TypeError**:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int
```

Por lo qué habría que convertirlo a `str`:

```
fichero_salida.write(str(min(numbers)))
```

**Código final**:

```
numbers = []

with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as file_numbers:
    for number in file_numbers:
        numbers.append(int(number))

with open('final.txt', 'a') as fichero_salida:
    fichero_salida.write('%d\n' % min(numbers))
    fichero_salida.write('%d\n' % max(numbers))
```

---

**EDITO**:

Lo voy a hacer de una forma básica y detallada:

```
lista = []

# Abrimos fichero que contiene los números:
fichero_a = open('numbers.txt','r')

# Por cada elemento de este fichero, lo convertimos a entero y lo añadimos 
# a lista que tenemos previamente vacía:
for i in fichero_a:
    lista.append(int(i))

# Cerramos fichero origen
fichero_a.close()

# Resultado de lista:
# [1, 10, 3, 5, 2, 4, 1, 2, 12, 14, 51, 21, 100, 9, 76, 45, 23, 45, 12]

# Guardamos el mayor y menor número:
numero_menor = min(lista)
numero_mayor = max(lista)

# Guardamos la posición del mayor elemento, para eliminarlo de la lista y poder añadirlo 
# al principio. Ten en cuenta que si por ejemplo, el número 100 es el mayor y se repite 
# dos veces, solo cogerá la primera vez que se encuentre este número:
posicion_mayor_elemento = lista.index(max(lista))
posicion_menor_elemento = lista.index(min(lista))

# Lo eliminamos de la lista:
lista.pop(posicion_mayor_elemento)
lista.pop(posicion_menor_elemento)

# Los añadimos al principio:
lista.insert(0, numero_menor)
lista.insert(0, numero_mayor)

# Resultado de la lista:
# [10, 0, 3, 5, 2, 4, 1, 2, 12, 14, 51, 21, 9, 76, 45, 23, 45, 12, 0]

# Abrimos fichero resultado:
fichero_b = open('final.txt', 'a')

# Recorremos cada elemento de la lista, lo convertimos a string y lo
# añadimos al fichero con un salto de línea:
for numero in lista:
    fichero_b.write(str(numero)+"\n")

# Cerramos el fichero:
fichero_b.close()
```

El **contenido del fichero final**:

```
100
1
10
3
5
2
4
1
2
12
14
51
21
9
76
45
23
45
12
```

Donde está el 100 y el 1 como mayor y menor.

Comment: Hola, buenas tardes.La forma with.........as,no me la han enseñado, lo que has hecho tú, yo lo hacía pero poniendo fichero_a=open('numbers.txt','r') y me daba error, posiblemente por no convertirlo a entero. y otra cuestión a la hora de ponerlo en el otro archivo tienen que aparecer todos los números con el mayor y el menor en primera y segunda posición, comprendo que con lo que has puesto sólo salen primero y segundo y el resto de números no. Saludos y gracias de antemano

Comment: No hay problema. Puedo editar y usar `open` y `close`. El `with` es solo para que no tengas que "preocuparte" de cerrar el handle del fichero. ¿Podrías, por favor, editar la pregunta y comentar como quieres que se guarden en el fichero? No comprendo exactamente a que te refieres con "tienen que aparecer todos los números con el mayor y el menor en primera y segunda posición". ¿Algo como? `10   1  restoDeNúmeros?` ¿En qué orden el resto de números?

Comment: 10 primera posición, 1 segunda posición y después el resto de números cada uno en una posición y de forma completamente aleatoria

Comment: y en columna,como están en el txt inicial

Comment: No has subido el contenido de tu txt por lo que usé uno de ejemplo como el que ves en la respuesta. He editado la respuesta y he colocado el código a partir de "EDITO". Es una forma básica de hacerlo pero para lo que necesitas entiendo que te sirve.

Comment: Sólo una última pregunta, si el elemento está el último de la lista y al aplicar el método pop me da pop index out of range, ¿como lo soluciono, sumando 1?

Comment: Lo he hecho como tú dices y me sigue dando error, esta vez al pasarlo al otro archivo me da un ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: Añade el contenido que tienes en el fichero numeros5_4.txt de esta forma podemos trabajar sobre tu contenido. Lo que te coloqué es un ejemplo para que miraras como desarrollarlo más o menos (una de varias formas que hay) y de esta forma puedas adaptar lo que tienes y también entender cómo funciona.

Comment: Disculpa la tardanza en contestar, problemas familiares,el documento numeros5_4.txt es idéntico al que tú has utilizado, un archivo de texto con un numero por fila.

Comment: No te preocupes. Extraño, debería funcionar. He copiado el código de nuevo y el mismo .txt de ejemplo y me ha procesado todo bien. Intenta copiarlo de nuevo.

Comment: Bueno, da igual, lo doy por bueno, entiendo la lógica y evidentemente el fallo no debe estar en el código, aunque en el insert  no entiendo que los dos números(mayor y menor) ocupen la posición 0

Comment: En cuanto a la posición recuerda que siempre se comienza a contar desde 0 en un `array`. Las listas son "como" arrays. Por lo que siempre el primer elemento será 0. Si quiero insertar en la primera posición, por ejemplo, se empezará a contar desde 0. Esto implica también lo mismo en otros aspectos, por ejemplo, al intentar acceder a un elemento, e.g: `lista[0]`.

Comment: Y una última pregunta respecto a otro código que estoy implementando, es sobre un texto que hay que copiar en otro archivo, pero ese texto txt, descompuesto en palabra por linea, mi lógica ha sido la siguiente

Comment: Utilizar un contador para que con un for cuente por cada palabra, si suma más de 1 añadirle un '\n', creo que es lo lógico pero no sale nada

Comment: Depende de como quieras el resultado. Si guardas toda la frase que leas del fichero en una lista, y solamente quieres imprimir línea por línea cada palabra, con un for recorriendo cada palabra de la lista e imprimiendo la plabra te serviría. Si quieres añadir cada palabra en una nueva lista y que cada palabra finalice con un '\n' a excepción de la última, puedes recorrer la primera lista, colocar un contador a 0, si el contador es menor que la longitud de la lista - 1, añades a una nueva lista la palabra con salto de línea, sino (else) añades la palabra sin más.

Comment: Mejor añade otra pregunta con lo que has intentado si te hace falta y la comunidad te ayudará, de esta forma no hacemos debates extensos en las respuestas de forma innecesaria.

Comment: Ok, muchísima gracias

Comment: De nada. Si la respuesta te ha servido de ayuda puedes validarla. Saludos!